# Does $u=\Psi^{-1}\circ L\circ \Phi\iff L=\Psi\circ u\circ \Phi^{-1}$. Same question with matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra

**Q1)** $u\in \mathcal L(E,F)$ with $E$ and $V$ finite vector spaces over $K$. If $\Phi:E\to K^n$ and $\Psi:F\to K^p$ are isomorphisms, and if $$u=\Psi^{-1}\circ L\circ \Phi,$$
with $L:K^n\to K^p$ linear. Does we get that $$\Psi\circ u\circ \Phi^{-1}=L \ \ ?$$

I would say yes since $$u=\Psi^{-1}\circ L\circ \Phi\iff u\circ \Phi=\Psi^{-1}\circ L\circ \Phi\circ \Phi^{-1}=\Psi^{-1}\circ u\iff \Psi\circ u\circ \Phi^{-1}=\Psi\circ \Psi^{-1}\circ L=L,$$
but I have doubt with composition at right...

**Q2)** If $A=P^{-1}BQ$ with $P$ ans $Q$ invertible, does we get $$B=P A Q^{-1} \ \ ??$$

My problem is that $$A=P^{-1}BQ\iff Ax=P^{-1}BQx\iff PAx= BQx$$
but I guess that it's wrong that $$PAx=BQx\iff PAQ^{-1}x=BQQ^{-1}x=Bx,$$
so may be what I'm saying is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and yes but not as written.

For Q2), you have to set $u=Qx$ and thus you get $$PAQ^{-1}u=Bu.$$ But you can't compose by the right in the sense that $$Ax=Bx\not\Rightarrow ACx=BCx.$$

For Q1) it's the same problem. You have to set $u=\Phi(x)$ and then get $$\Psi\circ u (x)=L\circ \Phi(x)\iff \Phi\circ u\circ \Phi^{-1}(u)=L(u),$$

but you can't compose by the right in the sense that $$f(x)=g(x)\not\Rightarrow f(h(x))=g(h(x)).$$